# The need for a voting drive?

Tags: discussion, voting

It is a very frustrating look at the voting tab in the users category.

The last Hot Network Question attracted so many votes, even from users apparently only registering with this community to vote and comment on this one question.

There are members here, much longer registered than others, still looking after the queues, even still contributing content, but they have sometimes voted less than 30 times in over a year.

Going from site statistics and perceived activity, some of that visible in the queues, there are much more visitors than votes.

There is of course the quality problem so often lamented here on meta. But comparing the highest voted questions and answers to that what we as designed by the system consider "good enough" – questions that are *not closed* and answers that are *not removed* or *not downvoted*.

So what is the real reason for not voting? Especially in the case of regulars, and even more in the case of long term regulars still quite active otherwise?

Some reminders might be necessary?
[Why vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)
[Vote early, vote often](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/)

Is it really a problem of ["High Standards" Top 100 Users That Rarely Upvote](http://data.stackexchange.com/health/query/6856/high-standards-top-100-users-that-rarely-upvote)
It appears to me as connected but separate problem.

Why is voting so low? How do we increase the voting?

Comment: The questions are depressing so I avoid down voting everything

Comment: And it looks like even those who answer questions don't upvote the question

Comment: Nor those who vote to close even downvote the question.  Amusingly the close queue doesn't have the ability to downvote built in, you have to open the q (in the same or new tab) to downvote it - should be available to do while doing the queue lol

Comment: I occasionally lurk here but I rarely find a question worth either upvoting or answering unfortunately, same with Psych/Neuro.SE.

Comment: @DoctorWhom While you have pointed out a very valid missing feature request (is that on metaSE already?), the first round of close is not intended, in view, to destroy all posts, but to put them *on hold*, giving a chance to improve. 4 downvotes in that phase will likely demotivate anyone. I tried to follow the series of comment, put on hold, downvote, close (or leave closed). Immediate downvotes on Qs from newbies is very uninviting. And voting is needed in both directions.

Comment: If the user is a newbie with a question that needs closing it's unlikely that user is one we want.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Well said. I agree. And I still see a difference between the need for a Q to "put on hold" and "close". Newbies need some guidance, we want strictness and quality. In my view, at least a two step process. – Some need downright immediate closure.