# A challenge to vote

Tags: discussion, voting

There are currently 28 individuals who have cast over 200 votes: https://health.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=voters&filter=all and only 7 users with 1000+ votes cast. At a maximum of 40 votes a day, we have only voted on like 2% of the content (questions and answers). I have only cast 71 votes so less than 1% of the content.

I challenge everyone to find content to vote on (either upvote or down vote) and get you vote total up. If you want to play, post an answer with your vote summary and in 30 days we will see who has the greatest increase in votes.

Comment: Related: [Need for voting drive](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/837/11231). As much as I agree on "more votes please", do not vote indiscriminately but according to your judgement of the content or its usefulness. We have great stuff on the site – and pretty bad stuff by our current standards. Let your votes reflect that. (Otherwise it is not only against policy but also really hurting the site.)

Comment: @LangLangC yes. I was suggesting vote the good stuff up and the bad stuff down. Hopefully more than 2% of the content is either clearly good or clearly bad.

Comment: Okay, so maybe I'm being dense, but vote on _**what**_?

Comment: @CareyGregory the challenge is to read through old questions and answers and find ones that are worthy of up and down votes. As you have already cast over 1700 votes it might be a challenge for you to find stuff.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, that's not likely to be a productive use of my time. However, I am often surprised when I see old questions being resurrected that I didn't vote on. I try to fix that as I see them.

Comment: Related: https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/726/the-excellent-answers-of-health-se

Comment: Hm. While that might no help so much with showing of numbers here: I just noticed that quite a few of the meta-posts in recent months are also in need of differentiation and appreciation by votes. If anyone feels the need to click an arrow, do it here on meta as well! And remember, downvotes on meta do not hurt rep wise…

Answer (score 2):

Strongbad: https://health.stackexchange.com/users/55/strongbad

```
Votes Cast (71)
all time        by type         month    
65  up          45  question        3   
6   down        26  answer
```

Comment: BTW: The votes tab seems to count differently. Including review votes? Anyway, you should include that number as well (and it's likely higher for you as well)? CM is not unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @LangLangC as my vote count states that I cast 40 votes within the last month and none this week but I check the review queues very regularly.

In fact I checked this morning and apart from a couple of tag edits which I voted on, **and they haven’t been added to my vote count either**, my review queue is empty.

I still have 0 votes this week yet I have been voting this week.

Comment: Well, there is a difference between *reviewing* and *voting*. If you reviewed some suggested edits, the reviews are shown in your recent activity in [the reviews tab](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews). Upvotes and downvotes are a separate thing - you can check the posts you have voted [in the votes tab](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes) on your profile. (The wording "tag edits which I voted on" suggests that you meant reviews rather then actual upvotes/downvotes on posts. Only the latter count towards number of votes.)